# wpf project to pixelsense application

Tags: pixelsense, projects

I'm trying to write a Microsoft surface application for Samsung sur40 pixelsense machine. I have found some sample projects online and run them on the MS Visual C# 2010, but I want to convert these projects into applications so that I can put them into Samsung sur40 and run them in its surface mode. Do you know how I can actually achieve this?

In order to write these type of applications, I am using the following OS, programs and tools.

> Embedded Windows 7 Professional 64-bit
>   Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express Edition
>   .NET Framework 4.0
>   Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) 4.0
>   Microsoft XNA® Framework 4.0
>   Windows PowerShell and DMTF DASH support, and enhanced administrator tools 
>   MS Surface 2.0 SDK(an Input Simulator allows me to develop and test projects on Windows 7 PCs)

Everything is working properly and I can test the sample projects on my PC. I just want to make a Visual Studio project to run in the Samsung sur40 machine. Please help me if it is possible? If you need further explanations to answer my question, please let me know and I try to expand the problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, did the given answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Menual install !

you can't see the folder "c:\ProgramData" 
because the folder's option hide~

so..

1. C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Surface\v2.0\Programs   --> copy and paste!! and find!!
2. you create a shortcut of the ApplicationName.XML in your project for MS Surface applicaion
3. copy  shortcut file  and  paste --> "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Surface\v2.0\Programs"

and following this steps :

1. In Windows mode, click Start, click All Programs, click Microsoft Surface 2.0, and then click Surface Configuration Editor
2. In the left pane, click Application Launcher.
3. In the Application Launcher pane, in the Launcher title box, type the title text you want to appear above Launcher.

   The title text will be placed just above the Launcher menu and is left-justified. You cannot change the font, font size, font color, justification, or location of the text.
4. Click OK to save your setting and close Surface Configuration Editor, or click Apply to save your setting and continue configuring Surface. Restart Surface Shell for your settings to take effect.

click : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680380.aspx